# Finding maximum edge weight in Spark GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Let`s say I have a graph with double values for edge attributes and I
want to find the maximum edge weight of my graph. If I do this:

```
val max = sc.accumulator(0.0) //max holds the maximum edge weight
g.edges.distinct.collect.foreach{ e => if (e.attr > max.value) max.value
= e.attr }
```

I want to ask how much work is done on the master and how much on the
executors, because I know that collect() method brings the entire RDD to
the master? Does a parallelism happen? Is there a better way to find the
maximum edge weight?

NOTE:

```
g.edges.distinct.foreach{ e => if (e.attr > max.value) max.value =
e.attr } // does not work without the collect() method.
//I use an accumulator because I want to use the max edge weight later
```

And if I want to apply some averaging function to the attributes of edges that have same srcId and dstId between two graphs, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either aggregate:

```
graph.edges.aggregate(Double.NegativeInfinity)(
  (m, e) => e.attr.max(m),
  (m1, m2) => m1.max(m2)
)
```

or map and take max:

```
 graph.edges.map(_.attr).max
```

Regarding your attempts:

1. If you collect all data is processed sequentially on a driver so there is no reason to use an `accumulator`.
2. it doesn't work because accumulators are write-only from a worker perspective.